# general question about solving problems with parallelisation

Tags: c, openmp, mpi

i have a general question about programming of parallel algorithms in C. Lets assume that our task is to implement some matrix algorithms with MPI and/or OpenMP. There are some situations, like false sharing in OpenMP or in MPI where the communications arise in dependence of the matrix dimension (columns cyclic distrubuted among processes), which cause some problems . Would it be a good and a common attempt to solve this situations by, for example, transposing the matrix, because this would reduce the necessary communications or even avoiding the false sharing problem? After that you would undo the transposition. Of course, assuming that this would lead to a much better speed up.
I dont think that this would be very cunning and more of a lazy way to do this. But im curious to read some opions about this.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the first question first: can it make sense to transpose?   The answer is, it depends, and you can estimate whether it will improve things or not.

The transposition/retransposition with impose a one-time memory bandwidth cost of 2*(going through memory the fast way) + 2*(going through memory the slow way) where those memory operations are literally memory operations in the multicore case, or network communications in the distributed memory case.    You're going to be reading a matrix in the fast way and putting it into memory the slow way.    (You can make this, essentially, 4*(going through memory the fast way) by reading the matrix in one cache-sized block at a time, transposing in cache, and writing out in order).

Whether or not that's a win or not depends on how many times you'll be accessing the array.  If you would have been hitting the entire non-transposed array 4 times with memory access in the "wrong" direction, then you will clearly win by doing the two transposes.   If you'd only be going through the non-transposed array once in the wrong direction, then you almost certainly won't win by doing the transposition.

As to the larger question,   @AlexandreC is absolutely right here -- trying to implement your own linear algebra routines is madness.   Take a look at, eg, [How To Write Fast Numerical Code](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~franzf/papers/gttse07.pdf), figure 3; there can be factors of 40 in performance between naive and highly-tuned (say) GEMM operations.   These things are highly memory-bandwidth limited, and in parallel that means network limited.   By far, best is to use existing tools.

For multicore linear algebra, existing libraries include

- [Atlas](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/)
- [Plasma](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/plasma/overview/index.html)
- [Flame](http://z.cs.utexas.edu/wiki/flame.wiki/FrontPage)

For MPI implementations, there are

- [BLACS](http://www.netlib.org/blacs/)
- [Scalapack](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/)

or complete solver environments like

- [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-as/)
- [Trilinos](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/)

Comment: Thx for your detailed answer. I wish I could use the existing tools. It is my task to do it only with the MPI and OpenMP library. I wish there would be some good examples for my case.

Comment: A question: "The transposition/retransposition with impose a one-time memory bandwidth cost of ..." - To transpose a matrix, isn't it enough to swap the row/column indices, without moving anything?

Comment: @Pietro - the question is here is about actually reordering the data in memory to speed access.  For instance, in doing matrix-matrix multiplication, one matrix gets accessed the fast way, by rows, and the other gets accessed the slow way, by columns.  No index reordering can change the fact that the memory access patterns are different and one of the two will be accessed in a cache-unfriendly way.  So to answer this part of the question one actually has to consider moving the data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you'd throw the transpose away the second that you completed the operation, but yes this is a valid mechanism to increase parallelism.

I am not an expert; I've only read a little bit about this topic, and even that was for SIMD architectures, so please take my opinion lightly... but I think the usual mechanism is to lay your structures out in memory to match the machine (so you'd transpose a large matrix to line up better with your vectors and increase the dependency distance in your loops), and then you also build an indexing structure of pointers around that so that you can quickly access individual elements in the transpose differently. This gets more difficult to do as your input changes more dynamically.

Comment: I thought about this because i have to implement a parallel back substitution algorithm with cylcic distrubted columns of a matrix in MPI. If I wouldnt do the transposition, there would be two communcation operations minimum in every step.

Comment: @Eddie: did you check PBLAS and ScaLAPACK ? I would definitely not reinvent the wheel here. There are routines for distributed backsubstitution there http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/slug/node51.html#SECTION04331000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

> I dont think that this would be very cunning and more of a lazy way to do this.

Lazy solutions are usually better than "cunning" ones, because they tend to be more simple and straightforward. They're therefore easier to implement, document, understand and maintain. Indeed, laziness is arguably one of the greatest virtues a programmer can have. As long as the program produces correct results at acceptable speeds, nobody should care how elegantly you solved the problem (including you).